# SQL select output after inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, output, inner-join

I have one problem. 
I have 2 tables, and I performed an `inner join` on people id. Now I want that names of those people write. I tried this but it writes name of first on first and second.

```
SELECT g.id, g.idobject, 
       p.name || ' ' || z.last as Per1,
       p.name || ' ' || z.last as Per2
    FROM
        grup g 
           INNER JOIN people p on g.idper1=p.id 
           INNER JOIN people p on g.iper2=p.id
```

Comment: When joining the same table twice, use **different** aliases.

Comment: Mysql uses the `CONCAT()` function to concatenate strings, not `||`.

Answer (score 2):

When joining the same table twice, use different aliases.

For example:

```
SELECT g.id, g.idobject, 
       concat(p1.name, ' ', p1.last) as Per1,
       concat(p2.name, ' ', p2.last) as Per2
    FROM
        grup g 
           INNER JOIN people p1 on g.idper1=p1.id 
           INNER JOIN people p2 on g.iper2=p2.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should fail.  You need different table aliases:

```
SELECT g.id, g.idobject, 
       p1.name || ' ' || p1.last as Per1,
       p2.name || ' ' || p2.last as Per2
FROM grup g JOIN
     people p1 
     ON g.idper1 = p1.id JOIn
     people p2
     ON g.iper2 = p2.id;
```

If you are indeed using MySQL, then the appropriate function is `CONCAT()` or better yet, `CONCAT_WS()`:

```
SELECT g.id, g.idobject, 
       CONCAT_WS(' ', p1.name, p1.last) as Per1,
       CONCAT_WS(' ', p2.name, p2.last) as Per2
FROM grup g JOIN
     people p1 
     ON g.idper1 = p1.id JOIn
     people p2
     ON g.iper2 = p2.id;
```

Comment: I usually feel silly using `CONCAT_WS()` when there are just two strings. :)

Comment: @Barmar . . . It handles `NULL` values elegantly.